# Maximum Contiguous Subsequence Sum and sequence

Tags: java, sum, sequence

I am trying to find to the max sum of an array and print the corresponding sequence that produces that max sum. I have been able to get the correct sum but when I try to print the sequence for some of the test arrays my program leaves off one of the indices. For example, for the array [1, -1, 2, 3, -2] my program finds the max sum of 5 but it only prints 1, -1, 2 instead of 1, -1, 2, 3. I know the problem is inside my for loop and my count variable not incrementing correctly but I do not know how to fix it.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class practice
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int arr[] = {1, -1, 2, 3, -2};
            int arr2[] = {1, 12, -2, -15, 10};
            int arr3[] = {0, -1, -3, -5, -6};
            int arr4[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            int arr5[] = {1, 12, -2, 15, 10};

            subsequence(arr);
            subsequence(arr2);
            subsequence(arr3);
            subsequence(arr4);
            subsequence(arr5);

        }

        public static void subsequence(int[] arr)
        {
            int max = 0;
            int tempMax = 0;
            int count = 0;

            // My problem is in here:
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                tempMax += arr[i];
                if (max < tempMax)
                {
                    max = tempMax;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("count = " + count);
            System.out.println("Max sum is " + max);
            System.out.print("Sequence is: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

here is my output

```
    count = 3
    Max sum is 5
    Sequence is: 1 -1 2 

    count = 2
    Max sum is 13
    Sequence is: 1 12 

    count = 0
    Max sum is 0
    Sequence is: 

    count = 5
    Max sum is 15
    Sequence is: 1 2 3 4 5 

    count = 4
    Max sum is 36
    Sequence is: 1 12 -2 15
```

here is my edited code:

```
public class practice
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = {1, -1, 2, 3, -2};
        int arr2[] = {1, 12, -2, -15, 10};
        int arr3[] = {0, -1, -3, -5, -6};
        int arr4[] = {-1, 2, 3, -4, -5};
        int arr5[] = {1, 12, -2, 15, 10};

        subsequence(arr);

        subsequence(arr2);

        subsequence(arr3);

        subsequence(arr4);

        subsequence(arr5);
    }

    public static void subsequence(int[] arr)
    {
        int max = 0;
        int tempMax = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;

        if (arr[0] < 0)
           start++;


        for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            tempMax += arr[i];

            if (max < tempMax)
            {
                max = tempMax;
                count = i;
            }

            if (Math.abs(arr[i]) < tempMax)
               end = i;


         }

         System.out.println("count = " + count);
         System.out.println("Max sum is " + max);
         System.out.print("Sequence is: ");

         if (arr[end] < 0)
               end--;

         for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
             System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");

         System.out.println("\n");
         }

    }
```

and here is my new output:

```
count = 3
Max sum is 5
Sequence is: 1 -1 2 3 

count = 1
Max sum is 13
Sequence is: 1 12 

count = 0
Max sum is 0
Sequence is: 0 

count = 2
Max sum is 5
Sequence is: 2 3 

count = 4
Max sum is 36
Sequence is: 1 12 -2 15 10
```

Comment: you said this  prints 1, -1, 2 instead of 1, -1, 2, 3 but what happened -2 here?

Comment: the reason -2 does not show up is because it does not create a max sum. if -2 was included it would make the sum equal to 3 when the actual max sum is 5.

Comment: what is the rule to come up with it?

Comment: @assylias but the question requires the max contiguous sum.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @Eran I had not realised - you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `count` variable doesn't make sense, since you only increment it if you find a new candidate for the maximum. When you find a new maximum candidate, set count to the current index :

```
count = i;
```

Then when you print the sequence, change the condition to `j <= count`.

BTW, I'm not sure your implementation is correct. You always return a sub-sequence that starts in the beginning of the array. What if the sub-sequence with the max sum doesn't start at the beginning? (for example, in [-1,2,3,4,5], the max sequence is [2,3,4,5]).

Comment: what is max sequence here? what does it mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski The max sequence is the sub-array that produces the max sum.

Comment: I did not consider that. any suggestions on how to go about that? Also i would like to just print 2, 3 instead of 1, -1, 2, 3

Comment: what is the logic behind that?

Comment: the reason i want to just print 2, 3 is because 1 and -1 cancel each other out so there is no need to print them

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/
check this out it may help you

Comment: @shane The naive way is to use a nested loop. The outer loop from 0 to array.length - 1. The inner loop from i to array.length - 1. The inner loop will find the max sum of a sequence starting in i. The outer loop would find the overall max sum.

Comment: @shane You could do it much better though, with a single pass. First of all, you can safely discard all the negative values at the beginning of the array. Then set the start of the sequence to be the first positive value. Then, each time you encounter a negative value, if it's absolute value is lower than your current maximum, add it to the sequence. If not, remember the start and end of the current max sequence (the end being the last number before the negative number), and try to find a sequence with a higher maximum that starts after that negative number.

Comment: @Eran - i tried to following what you suggested but my program is still not showing the right results. I have added them to above

Comment: @shane You didn't follow it correctly, and come to think of it, it's more complicated than I wrote in the comment. You could have several positive values followed by several negative values followed by several positive values. To determine whether the negative values should be part of the sequence, you should check if the absolute value of their sum is lower than either the sum of the positive numbers before them or the sum of the positive numbers following them. That's a complicated condition to code. Perhaps you should try the simpler naive solution first.